# Is there a cleaner way of organising multiple RXJS observables inside a merge?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

The epic below works as intended. It calls multiple actions inside the merge operator before making the api call. However, I'm just wondering is there a cleaner way of calling the reset actions than listing the separate observables as I have. Is it possible to list them inside an array? Or some other way?

```
const imageUploadEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('UPLOAD_IMAGE'),
    mergeMap(action =>
      concat(
        merge(
          of({ type: 'RESET_IMAGE' }),
          of({ type: 'RESET_COLOURS' }),
          of({ type: 'RESET_LOCALISER' })
        ),
        from(
          axios.post(`/uploads/url`, {
            url: action.src
          })
        ).pipe(
          map(response => ({
            type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS',
            data: response.data,
          })),
          catchError(error =>
            of({
              type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_ERROR',
              error
            })
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that [`concat`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/concat) accepts `ObservableInput` parameters and an array is an `ObservableInput`:

```js
const imageUploadEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('UPLOAD_IMAGE'),
    mergeMap(action =>
      concat(
        [
          { type: 'RESET_IMAGE' },
          { type: 'RESET_COLOURS' },
          { type: 'RESET_LOCALISER' }
        ],
        from(axios.post(`/uploads/url`, { url: action.src })).pipe(
          map(response => ({
            type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_SUCCESS',
            data: response.data,
          })),
          catchError(error =>
            of({
              type: 'UPLOAD_IMAGE_ERROR',
              error
            })
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

Comment: The answer is correct but you should use `concat` instead of `merge` - `concat` is guaranteed to keep order. (OP also uses `concat`)